# goutteを使ったスクレイピング

Tags: php, web-scraping

goutteを使ったスクレイピングについて勉強しています。

例えば、はてなブックマークの「テクノロジー」カテゴリのホットエントリーのリストを取得してみようといろいろ試行錯誤していますがうまくいきません。

例えば、ページ上の「.entry-link」クラスを取得すればエントリーのリンクを取得できます。

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://b.hatena.ne.jp/hotentry/it');

$crawler->filter('.entry-link')->each(function ($node) {
    echo $node->html() . "\n";
});
```

しかしこの場合は、ホットエントリー以外にも下部にある「人気エントリー」も抽出されてしまうため、上部のリストのみとりたいのですがどうすればうまく指定できるかわかりません。

何れも「box_section」クラスの中に存在しているので、「box_section」の一つ目にふくまれる「entry-link」を抽出するように指定するべきだと思うのですが、うまくいきません。

試しに以下のようにしていましたがやはりだめでした。

```
$box = $crawler->filter('.box_section');

$box->filter('.entry-link')->each(function ($node) {
    echo $node->text() . "\n";
});
```

どのように絞り込めばよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はてなブックマークの見方が分からないので、見当違いかもしれませんが・・・

参考URL下部の新着エントリーを読むボタン下、
「人気エントリー - プログラミング」以降を除外した記事のタイトルということですと

```
$crawler->filter(".box-wrap:nth-child(2) .entry-link")->each(function($node) {
    echo $node->html().PHP_EOL;
});
```

で取得できますよ。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。いただいた内容で無事取得できました。  
なお、もともと私の方で取得できていなかったのは、ブラウザ表示とスクリプトでの表示に違いがありその結果正常に取得できておりませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

Goutte の filter は CSS セレクタ で指定するはずですので、

```
$box->filter('.entry-link:nth-child(2)')
```

という指定を入れるか、

```
$box->filter('.entry-link')
```

でフィルタリングした要素を全て取得してオブジェクトまたは配列に入れ込み、
抽出してしまうのがいいかなと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

そもそも「filter('.box_section')」では何も取得できていないようです。
原因は全くわかりません…その為、結局階層をたどった絞り込みはできませんでした。

Comment: ↓のコードでも取得できないでしょうか？
    $crawler->filter('.box_section')->each(function ($node) {
        echo $node->html() . "\n";
    });

Comment: いろいろ試したところ、HTML構造を確認するのにchromeを使っていたのですが、その再に表示方法の変更操作を行っていたようです。その影響で取得できなかったようです。その後、表示形式をデフォルトにしたところ問題なく取得することができました。  おさわがせしました。